# Combining Date and Time series columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

[image]

I have excel file which contains Date and Time data in separate columns. Their type is pandas core series.
I need to combine these two columns into one column in order to do further analysis.

How to combine these columns in the right way?

I tried to combine them by using pandas.to_datetime() function, but got an error:

```
In: df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+df['Time'])
Out: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'datetime.time'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with casting times to strings and add to column `Date`:

```
df['dt'] = df['Date']+pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str))
```